# WiX : Windows Service fails to start as App.config is not yet modified

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, custom-action, deferred-execution

I have created a **Windows Service Installer** using **WiX 3.8**, everything works fine except that the service does not start upon installation, I have written a custom action which modifies the **app.config** with the user input values, the service fails to start because the **app.config** is not yet modified.

Is there a way I can schedule modifying App.config before the attempt to start the service is made?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: In a rush, but your custom action must be scheduled before the StartServices action in the InstallExecuteSequence.

Comment: Did that, but the custom action does not find the App.config file

Comment: You need a deferred mode custom action.

Comment: I get this error Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.InstallerException: Cannot access session details from a non-immediate custom action

Comment: This is a complicated topic, this may help: **[deferred mode execution](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-access-windows-installer-property-deferred-execution)**. And **[this SDK information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370543(v=vs.85).aspx)**. And an [plainer language explanation](http://www.installworld.com/index.php?view=article&catid=40%3Awindows-installer&id=88%3Ahow-can-i-provide-data-to-my-deferred-custom-action&option=com_content&Itemid=136).

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom action run deferred and schedule it to run after InstallFiles and before StartServices, for example:

```
<CustomAction Id="SomeAction"
            DllEntry="SomeEntry"
            Return="ignore"
            Execute="deferred"
            BinaryKey="CA.dll"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SomeAction" After="InstallFiles"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```